# llply operations on multiple dataframes

Tags: r

Is there a simple way (i.e., without having to use "for" loops) to do the following:

I have a couple data frames. I want to use a *plyr* operation to summarize them. In this example, I have two data frames, east and west, and I want to summarize both of them with spend and trials by country.

Here's the example data frames:

```
west <- data.frame(
    spend = sample(50:100,50,replace=T),
    trials = sample(100:200,50,replace=T),
    country = sample(c("usa","canada","uk"),50,replace = T)
    )

east <- data.frame(
    spend = sample(50:100,50,replace=T),
    trials = sample(100:200,50,replace=T),
    country = sample(c("china","japan","skorea"),50,replace = T)
    )
```

and the combined list of both dataframes:

```
combined <- c(west,east)
```

What I want to do is a ddply-type operation on both of these dataframes at the same time, and have the output be a list (at least that seems most straightforward). For example, if I were just operating on one dataframe, it would be something like:

```
country.df <- ddply(west, .(country), summarise,
    spend = sum(spend),
    trials = sum(trials)
)
```

But I want to do this at scale. I tried using similar syntax in the llply argument but that doesn't work (I have a feeling I'm missing something painfully obvious):

```
countries.list <- llply(combined, .(country), summarise,
    spend = sum(spend),
    trials = sum(trials)
)
```

That returns the error: "Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : attempt to apply non-function"

... I can think of a way to do this by writing a function, then passing that through to an apply argument. But it seems like *llply* should be able to handle this "out of the box" since it's a fairly straightforward use of what the tool does.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See also http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html - I'd strongly recommend storing your data in a single data frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
combined <- list(east, west)

lapply(combined, ddply, .(country), summarise, spend  = sum(spend),
                                               trials = sum(trials))

# [[1]]
#   country spend trials
# 1   china  1572   2976
# 2   japan  1075   1989
# 3  skorea  1262   2526
# 
# [[2]]
#   country spend trials
# 1  canada  1459   3117
# 2      uk   910   1967
# 3     usa  1248   2660
```

Comment: Okay that works and is exactly what I'm looking for... but I had no idea you could do that, because it looks like you're passing two arguments to lapply (ddply and summarise)

Comment: everything after `ddply` are the `...` arguments to `lapply`, which are passed to the function being applied (here `ddply`).

Comment: Thanks flodel - perfect! Quick follow-up (indirectly related): How would I use the lapply syntax to add a factor variable to this new list? Say if trials < 1000 = "Good" and if trials > 1000 = "Bad"?

Comment: `status = if (trials < 1000) "Good" else "Bad"` but make sure you add it at the end, after `trials` has been replaced with `sum(trials)`.

Comment: +1 I always forget that ... in `lapply` takes arguments to fun, great example.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another solution that makes use of `dplyr`, which is a highly optimized version of `plyr` for data frames. `dplyr` syntax is very intuitive and IMHO a lot more readable than `plyr`. It wouldn't be an exaggaration to say that it reads more like poetry (at least to my eyes :) )

```
combine = list(west = west, east = east)
library(dplyr)
lapply(combined, function(dat){
   dat %.%
     group_by(country) %.%
     summarise(
       trials = sum(trials),
       spend = sum(spend)
     ) %.%
     mutate(
       status = ifelse(trials < 1000, "Good", "Bad")
     )
})
```

EDIT. For completeness, here is the `data.table` solution. Note that for large data frames, `dplyr` and `data.table` will eat `plyr` for lunch :)

```
library(data.table)
lapply(combined, function(dat){
  data.table(dat)[
  , list(trials = sum(trials), spend = sum(spend)),country][
  , status := ifelse(trials < 1000, "Good", "Bad")]
})
```

UPDATE 2: Here is a more consise version of `dplyr` solution

```
lapply(combined, chain, group_by(country),
  summarise(trials = sum(trials), spend = sum(spend)),
  mutate(status = ifelse(trials < 1000, "Good", "Bad"))
)
```

Comment: +1 but I'll have to disagree about it being a lot more readable than `plyr`. Comparing your answer to mine, especially their lengths, I'd say the opposite (IMHO).

Comment: I think you are confusing conciseness with readability. The `dplyr` code will make sense even to someone who has no idea of its syntax, whereas the `plyr` syntax is more cryptic. I love `plyr` and `data.table`, so I am all for conciseness, but there is a certain beauty about `dplyr` syntax, which is what I was pointing to.

Comment: Well, if you are talking about people who don't know anything about R, sure. But for the non-novice, I can tell what my code does in 2 seconds while it will take me 20 for yours. Readability is a bit subjective...

Comment: Come on @Ramnath admit it, you just get a kick out of using that new `%.%` pipe operator ;-)

Comment: @SlowLearner It is true what you say about %.% :). I have been a long time `plyr` user. But the performance benefits of using `dplyr` and readability of code far outweigh the benefits of conciseness (at least IMHO).

Comment: Wikipedia: *Readability is the ease in which text can be read and understood. Various factors to measure readability have been used, such as "speed of perception," "perceptibility at a distance," "perceptibility in peripheral vision," "visibility," "the reflex blink technique," "rate of work" (e.g., speed of reading), "eye movements," and "fatigue in reading."*

Comment: Did you just quote wikipedia? Shame on you!

Comment: @flodel I am not trying to debate the conciseness and readability of your code from an R user's perspective. I use `plyr` a lot myself and enjoy the syntax. I just find `dplyr` more intuitive, even to someone who doesn't know R.

Comment: I was not debating *very intuitive* but *a lot more readable*.

Comment: That is a fair statement.

Comment: @Ramnath, any reason for using `transform` here, given that it's not a `dplyr` command + [this](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/211)?

Comment: I didn't realize that `transform` is buggy with `dplyr`. I have edited my answer to use `mutate`. Thanks for the pointer @Arun.

Comment: Not sure if the OP *wants* to keep it as a list. But by binding them together (with an extra column, say ID) and grouping together with that ID col as well could be faster (on bigger lists) than `lapply`ing.